# Cannot add DHCPv6 reservation on Server 2012 R2 (error 20022)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server, dhcpv6

I am trying to add DHCPv6 reservations on a Windows Server 2012 R2, but I do not want to use the "random" IPv6 the server chose (convert lease to reservation), but I want to use another, specific IPv6. This operation fails, however, with error 20222 (address or DUID already in use).

I have tried to release the IP on the client using `ipconfig /release6`, which removes the IP from the client and from the list of leases on the server. However, it does not fix the problem.

I tried to remove the lease on the server using `Remove-DhcpServerv6Lease`, which removes the lease from the list of active leases, but does not fix the problem either.

I have tried doing the reservation when the scope is deactivated without success.

I have tried restarting the DHCP service without success either.

If I list the active leases using `Get-DhcpServerv6Lease -Prefix $prefix`, I can neither find the DUID nor the IPv6 I want to reserve, but the operation still fails.

Where does the server get the information that the IPv6/DUID is already in use and how can I fix this?

Comment: this will be helpful https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55d0463c-13c2-47b1-a4ce-2f6c062cd192/error-20022-dhcp-server-2012?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: @serverAdmin123: If I understand this correctly, the problem and solution described there only refer to scopes replicated via DHCP failover clustering. Is that correct?